# Difficulty with updating ClamAV

Tags: permissions, updates, clamav

As it says in the title, I am struggling to update ClamAV and I have traced the problem to the timeout settings in the freshclam.conf file. The timeout settings are at 30 seconds by default... except that a fresh install of the antivirus signatures takes almost two minutes, which means the process always results in a 'update failed' result. When I attempt to edit the (read-only) file, the OS says that I do not have permission to make the edit.

The ClamAV site gives very obscure and noob-phobic instructions on how to edit this folder, so basically useless.

Similar users with the same problem on this site mention nothing about folder permissions. Am I doing something wrong? Should the file be edited in the terminal? Any suggestions welcome, but be warned I am relatively new to Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you start by providing OS/release details, and are you using an installed system? or a *live* system?  (eg. Ubuntu install media using the "*Try Ubuntu*" or like option; I'm wondering what file you're talking about being RO)

Comment: OS 18.04 (I think) and I am using an installed version. The read only file freshclam.conf file I mentioned in the question. Path is /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf file. The file is not permitting me to edit the text values inside. I can open it with any old text edite, but it won't let me change anything. I literally just need to change the timeout in the file from 30 to 120 seconds. People with the same problem as mind mentioned that this is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

The `nano /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf` must be preceded by `sudo` to save the file to config
eg.: `sudo nano /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be THAT GUY who answers his own question, but I found a solution. I ended up using the 'Nano' editor which actually allowed me to change the values in the 'read only' file I mentioned earlier. I stumbled across this particular video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLyUZAabf40

Heres what I did:
I opened a terminal

Typed "nano /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf"

In the nano editor I located the ConnectionTimeout setting and changed the value from 30 to 120.

Saved and exited

Comment: The correct way to change the settings in **/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf** is to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam` in a terminal window. This way, you will be able to change the update server to a one closer to you, so that the 30" timeout period will not be exceeded. Other useful settings can also be configured this way.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but this did not work. I was indeed able to select the closest server after proceeding through the configuration tool, however it is not possible to download 90+Mb of the initial antivirus signatures in under 30 seconds. It would always reach about 83Mb and then display the error. Perhaps this is possible with an internet connection upwards of 50 Mbps, but mine is 20.

Comment: Try downloading the **main.cvd** database from http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd on the clamav.net official site. This is just a test download for you to see if it's faster. You should delete the file afterwards. If it's faster, I can write a bash script for you that will download all three update files, place them in the appropriate directory and change their ownership and permissions afterwards so that they can be used by `clamav` successfully. If the download is not any faster though, there's nothing much you can do to speed it up by configuring `clamav` or `freshclam`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did download the main.cvd from freshclam's website but I had no idea what to do with it. Wish I had the advice from your comment earlier. The majority of ClamAv updates are less than 500Kb, which is now downloaded in 0.0 seconds either way, so I can successfully update now. ClamTk also registers the signatures.